# Keith woods countdown timer DATETIME format Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, countdown

I have been playing with this for far too long now and thought I had better ask for some help as I really need to move on :) I'm very new to jquery

I have the Keith Wood's countdown timer displaying but, the time is wrong, the future date is 3 days in the future but, I'm getting 217224 days. The date is mysql DATETIME i.e; 2012-11-15 07:00:30

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I only need to display the Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds but, if I remove the Y, m nothing displays. Here's my code, I would be very great full of any help!

```
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date(<?php
    $time = strtotime($row['auto_accept']);
    echo date('Y', $time);
    echo date('m', $time);
    echo date('d', $time-1);
    echo date('H', $time);
    echo date('i', $time);
    echo date('s', $time);?>);
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay, format: 'dHMS'});
});
```

OK I seem to have it working using:

```
$(function () {
var austDay = new Date(<?php
    $endtime = strtotime($row['auto_accept']);
    echo date('Y,m,', $endtime);
    echo (date('j', $endtime)-30);
    echo date(',h,i,s', $endtime);
?>);

$('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay, format: 'dHMS'});
});
```

I just need to optimise the code a little better as Tomalak said, I'll check out the manual ;)

Comment: What in the world is the "Keith Wood's countdown timer"?

Comment: :) yeah probably should have included the link, I have added it above.

Comment: The fact that you use 6 separate calls to `date()` means that you did not even take the time to gloss over [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Don't you think that you're lacking some effort?

Comment: I was just desperate to get anything to work, once working I would look at other ways to make the code better. I have been trying different scripts and playing with the code for 2 days now, drunk more coffee and pulled more hair out than ever. I'm no pro to jquery or php but, one thing I'm not lacking is effort!. I like to learn through practice.

Comment: Okay, granted. But then again, the PHP page on `date()` shows right away that you can combine the format into one string, which by implication means you have not read it at all. So you've been pulling your hair out but you've not actually been desperate enough to sit down for half an hour and read the docs? (I don't want to come across as condescending. I criticize your problem solving strategy, not you personally.)

Comment: Touche, completely agree hence my question here for help solving the problem. I have never taken any classes in any kind of web development, all I have learn't has been from resources online and I have built some pretty complicated sites. I will usually find a script someone has built and adapt it into something I can use, probably not the best way of doing things but, I have learn't alot over the past 3 years of doing this.

Comment: So you're using JS in script Tags, which gets filled by PHP? You're making me vomit a little.

Comment: It works, that's all I need right now I can move on. In the future, when I have learnt more I'm sure I'll look back and vomit myself :)

Comment: @monsterboy - Did you try my solution? Did it help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read up on how to use PHP's date function and figure out how to get the date in one shot. This would take no more than 10 or 15 minutes of your time and will quickly show you why you don't need to call date so many times (and save you time in the future and show you how I did it below).

Second, it would probably be best if you used an Ajax call to get values from PHP into Javascript. The method below works but it's fugly.

Your PHP:

```
$timeToConvert = strtotime($row['auto_accept'] . ' -1 day');
```

Your JS:

```
var austDay = new Date(<?php echo $timeToConvert * 1000 ?>);
$('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay});
```

That should be all you need (I did not test this to make sure but it looks pretty simple so I expect this will work with the plugin you are using.)

Comment: Great stuff got it to work without the -1 day. Thanks a ton I have learn't something too :)